# Add some sort of label to multiple revisions

Tags: mercurial

It looks like tags and bookmarks can only be applied to a single revision. Is there a way to attach some sort of identifier to multiple revisions? I'm trying to query the repo to get all revision of a specific label name. Is there a way to attach some sort of label to multiple revisions to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with bookmarks, although not necessarily in the most elegant fashion. For example, you could "label" a bunch of commits with bookmark names like `mylabel-1`, `mylabel-2`, `mylabel-3`, etc. You could then search for the commits that have bookmarks beginning with `'mylabel'` using the following revset:

```
$ hg log -r "bookmark('re:^mylabel')"
```

See `hg help revisions.patternmatching` and `hg help revsets` for more information.

In principle the feature you're looking for could be added in a more elegant way using an extension. I'm not aware of an existing extension that implements commit labels.

Comment: Yea I thought about doing this way but felt I didn't want to keep counting with my names lol. I think the same thing would work with tags. Sigh... I guess what I'm looking for is not possible.